# Rails Routes: How to block requests from certain domains?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want to prevent Facebook or Chrome from archiving my page on visit by a user. We all know Facebook peeks at the links you are exchanging and is probably processing it in one way or another.

I want to protect the privacy of the users of my page.

Thus, is there a built-in way in Rails to accomplish blocking certain URLs? Or do I have to resort to other measures? If so, what would direction would that be?